# wordpress: problem with adding another rule with wp_rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-match

i set my wordpress permlink to `/%category%/%postname%` now i'm using Nextgen Gallery so when i have a gallery in a page it will be something like `/cat/page?gallery=10` i want to make it something like `cat/page/gallery id/` i tried alot with wp_rewrite ... but no luck ... any help ?

this is what i'm testing on .. it's not my code it's provided from wordpress ... i will put everything in its place when i found the way ... so don't worry i will not `flushRules` on `init` ... thanks a lot

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','wp_insertMyRewriteRules');
add_filter('query_vars','wp_insertMyRewriteQueryVars');
add_filter('init','flushRules');

// Remember to flush_rules() when adding rules
function flushRules(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

// Adding a new rule
function wp_insertMyRewriteRules($rules)
{
    $newrules = array();

    //i don't know what should i put here
    $newrules[''] = '';
    return $newrules + $rules;
    //
}

// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function wp_insertMyRewriteQueryVars($vars)
{
    array_push($vars, 'id');
    return $vars;
}
```

Comment: May I suggest: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ - I'd expect more people to have the know-how out there.

Comment: i posted there too !! ... i hope someone will help me in that !! thanks a lot for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this 2 URL points you on the right direction:

- http://code.google.com/p/nextgen-gallery/issues/detail?id=223
- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-nextgen-gallery-permalink

Perhaps a Google keyword search will save you a lot of time... :)

Regards.